# how to confirm? before install application in shopify

Tags: asp.net, .net, ruby-on-rails, shopify

I have created a shopify application. While I click on "install app" button from the application store of shopify, it's directly redirect to me in a callback URL. But what I want is: when click on "install app" button I need to display a confirm screen before installation.

See this for reference: ( I want to make like [this](http://apps.shopify.com/fliptabify)).

For the reference [jpg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU0k8.jpg)

Comment: What actions are performed in your Application Callback URL Page ?

Answer (score 1):

Shopify does this for you the first time the app is installed.  It's a similar process to how Facebook and Twitter apps work.  The first time you try and use it a permissions screen + confirmation button will pop up.  Subsequent installations won't do that since the shop has already authorized the application.